# Multiple views iphone app - starter

Tags: iphone, multiview

Hello I am quite new in iphone programming
and i am trying to create a new app with game elements

my problem is that i have a difficulty in undertanding delegates.. so in order to create multiple view this is what i have done 
i created a switchview method which is called every time a button is pressed in order to go to the next screen.

```
- (void)switchView:(UIView *)View1 toView:(UIView *)View2
{

[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.window cache:YES];
[window addSubview:View2];
[UIView commitAnimations];



}
```

My problem is that i want after the instruction to insert a viewController for video and then another one for finding and updating the location of the user..

Do i have to insert handle every viewcontroller from the AppDelegate.m 
or is there another way??

e.g  the following code normally goes into the AppDelegate.m for the MediaPlayerViewController

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
MediaPlayerViewController *vc = [[MediaPlayerViewController alloc] init];
[[self window] setRootViewController:vc];
[vc release];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

how do i make it so after pressing the e.g start button the next screen with the video player pops up??

I am such a beginner it would be really helpful if smbd can answer..

Thanksss

Comment: I forgot to add that is a windows based project

Answer (score 0):

From your description and code snippets it looks like you have manually implemented a UINavigationController - and in the process created a lot of work for yourself.

Apple provide the UINavigationContoller class as a core part of the UIKit framework for presenting users with a hierarchy of views.  This hierarchy is implemented using a stack data structure, where the stack is composed of a number of UIViewController instances.  The usage of a stack fits well with the navigation paradigm, as the user moves through the navigation hierarchy more views are pushed onto the stack.  Take for example the Contacts app, its UINavigationController contains at first a UIViewController listing all contacts.  Subsequently when a user taps on a contacts name they are presented with that contact's information.  This translates to a new UIViewController containing the contact's information being pushed onto the UINavigationController's stack.  Subsequently when the user moves back to the list of contacts they pop the contact information UIViewController from the stack.

The easiest way to see how this all works in practice is to create a new 'Navigation Based' project and look at the code.

Comment: Thank you so much :)) hope that this will help me because i am kind of stuck..Thank you again

Comment: Now that I have seen the UINavigationController it is basically what i have done but in a windows based aplication from scratch everything works perftect untill it comes the time to play with video 

anybody has any idea why??

Comment: how do multiple views in windows based application works with video and CCLocation Manager??
can anybody help?? i cannot make it work..

Comment: http://www.colorcoat-online.com/blog/index.php/2011/05/15-iphone-apps-every-architect-must-have/   What i want is to do is like the first screen of the 9th app of the link above .. thank you..

Comment: I'm glad that helped, I would suggest creating a separate question with more information for any follow up questions you have.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you might be knowing about inbuilt video player, you can make use of this to play video which can be presented as modal view:

MPMoviePlayerViewController *m_MoviePlayer =[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:pUrl];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:m_MoviePlayer];